# How can I get the actual error from fetch api

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, fetch-api

I am making a fetch api call but in case of a 500 error the following middleware kicks in and sends back a json object in response body.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await next();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (context.Response.HasStarted)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                var json = JToken.FromObject(ex);
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(json.ToString());
            }
        });
```

On the client side I have the following code

```
 return fetch(url, content)
    .then(function(res) {
        if (!res.ok) {
            console.log(res, res.json())
            throw Error(res.statusText);
          }
        return res;
      })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(e => console.log('Error fetching accounts:', e))
```

## I am not able to access the json with error information. How can I do it ?

Working code after following the correct answer

```
return fetch(url, content)
       .then(function(response) {
           if (!response.ok) {
              return response.json()
                   .then(function(obj) {
                       throw Error(obj.ErrorMessage)
                   })
           } 
           else {
              return response.json()
                               .then(json => {
                                   /*further processing */
                               })
           }
       }).catch(/* work with the error */)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) function of the [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object returns a Promise, not the actual parsed value.

```
res.json()
.then(function(object) {
  // Here you have the parsed JSON object.
  console.log(object);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, it works now. I have updated with the working code but I feel it can be refactored further. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think the solution you proposed isn't bad. There are other options (e.g. https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8876465), but I like yours.

Comment: I was able to use some lambda to shorten this, thanks again !!